# Unity Android game: Screen turns off during gameplay

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I previously used buttons for movements in my game. Now I want to use the accelerometer for movement. Gameplay is great but the screen turns off during the game. I have used

```
Screen.sleepTimeout = SleepTimeout.NeverSleep;
```

but it's not working. How can I fix this issue?

Comment: I got it working by calling                                              Screen.sleepTimeout = SleepTimeout.NeverSleep; in Awake(). Previously i was calling it in Start().

Comment: thanks your answer . I will try .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I got it working by calling

Screen.sleepTimeout = SleepTimeout.NeverSleep; in Awake() method.

Previously i was calling it in Start() method.

Answer (score 1):

Try like this,

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class SleepDemo : MonoBehaviour
{
    void Awake() {
        Screen.sleepTimeout = SleepTimeout.NeverSleep;
    }

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start(){   
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update(){   
    }
}
```